# Install mysqldump on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have trouble installing the mysqldump utility on a Ubuntu Server. I tried with `apt-get install mysqldump` but i get `E: Unable to locate package mysqldump`.

I tried googling but couldn't find any quality information of the installation of mysqldump. I stumbled upon packages like `mysql-client-5.1` or thelike that might contain it.

But i am afraid it might somehow clash with the existing mysql installation. As i am no expert to the topic i wasn't able to gain enough information on the client packages, what they contain and if they will interfere. Can somebody help me find the right package and is it on top of mysql so it won't interfere with the current installation?

Comment: You must install mysql-client, which is a dependency of mysql-server (http://pastebin.com/h5cg6iDG), so it's strange that you haven't it installed. It must be the same version of the server.

Comment: Thank you... it is intalled. there was something wrong with the paths

Answer (score 95, accepted):

mysqldump is part of the package mysql-client and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

This will install the default version, often there are packages for other MySQL versions, e.g. mysql-client-5.5. The generic version should be suitable in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes apt-get wont get you the latest version, go to mysql site and download/unpack the mysql-community-client_*.*.*-1ubuntu16.04_i386.deb to get the mysqldump of the version you want. 
For example : mysql-community-client_5.7.26-1ubuntu16.04_i386.deb